# Excel, use file path to reference cell values in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, cell, filepath

I have a series of daily spreadsheets which are file by:

```
year / month / date
```

e.g.

```
/Users/myles/Dropbox (Green)/05_GM Vessels/Crew Dropbox/Green Isle/02_Daily Logs/2019 Logs/[GI_Daily_Log_30.07.2019.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$44
```

I would like to use a formula to extract the value within the specified cell (B44 in this case) and show it in a master / summary spreadsheet.

The files are in a different directory to the master / summary spreadsheet.

I have a formula which generates the above file path based on values in other cells.  E.G. `="["&$D$14&$W5&"/"&$A5&"]Sheet1'!$C$24"`

Which creates the following text within a cell;

```
[/Users/mylesmetson/Dropbox (Green Marine)/05_GM Vessels/Crew Dropbox/Green Isle/02_Daily Logs/2019 Logs/7_July/[GI_Daily_Log_29.07.2019.xlsm]Sheet1'!$C$24
```

Ideally I would like to remove the first / and then insert " =' " which if pasted as text into a cell, would then extract the value from this spreadsheet file and the referenced cell.  But this does not work.  instead I am having to do this manually in notepad and then copy & paste the entire text back into the cell.

Finally prior to excel retrieving the number in the referenced cell, I have to give permission / find the file location.

This is quite a complicated thing to explain and I have not found any other solutions on the internet which are 100% relevant to this scenario.  I think a macro may be required, but hopefully this can be done elsewise.

The indirect macro, would be ideal, apart from it requires the spreadsheets to be open, which is simply not practical either.

Thanks
for any help which can be provided.
Myles

Comment: Your Both Addresses are Different, One says `Dropbox (Green)` the other one says `Dropbox (Green Marine)` maybe that's the issue

Comment: Thanks, but this was intentionally changed.  I wanted to remove the full name, but then forgot with the next line.